# python opencv videocapture outputs distorted image

Tags: python, opencv

[1][the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0719G.jpg)
when running opencv videocapture the output is always distorted.
This is the code I used

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The program also crashes after a few seconds

Comment: I couldn't find any error in your code.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on updating OpenCV. Downgrading to version 4.2.0.34 solved the problem for me. This isn't a permanent solution however, but I guess we'll have to wait until the issue is resolved.

This is what I did:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python==4.2.0.34
```

The same code began to work after this change.